# What is the distance between these two points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm working from a textbook and am unsure if it's wrong (its probably me);

> Q) Find the lengths of the line segment joining this pair, assume a> 0.

$(a+1,2a+3)$ and $(a-1,2a-1)$

Following the equation;

$L =\sqrt {(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

With;

$x_2 = a-1$, $ x_1 = a+1$, $ y_2=2a-1, y_1=2a+3$

I get;

$L= \sqrt {((a-1)-(a+1))^2+((2a-1)-(2a+3))^2}$

Which to me means;

$L= \sqrt {(0)^2(2)^2}$

So,

$L= 2$

However, the book says;

$L=\sqrt{20}$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: If you subtract the two points you will get $(2,4)$. Then $\|(2,4)\| = \sqrt{2^2+4^2} = \sqrt{20}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
  \sqrt{((a-1) - (a+1))^2 + ((2a-1) - (2a+3))^2}
    &= \sqrt{(a-1-a-1)^2 + (2a-1-2a-3)^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sqrt{(-2)^2 + (-4)^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sqrt{4 + 16}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \sqrt{20}\\[0.3cm]
    &= 2\sqrt{5}
\end{align}

I can tell based on your question you'll probably need some more details explained.  Your very first step is correct, when you said
$$ L = \sqrt{((a-1) - (a+1))^2 + ((2a-1) - (2a+3))^2}. $$

But I have no idea how you got from there to $\sqrt{(0)^2(2)^2}$.  Also, that would equal 0, not 2.  Perhaps did you mean $\sqrt{(0)^2 + (2)^2}$?  That's close but still not quite right.

In any case, let's start from the beginning and look at one piece at a time.  The first piece we'll look at is the $((a-1) - (a+1))^2$.  The very first thing we need to do is distribute the minus sign into the $(a+1)$.  So we get:
$$ ((a-1) - (a+1))^2 = ((a-1) -a-1)^2 $$

The parentheses around the $a-1$ are unnecessary, so we get:
$$ ((a-1) -a-1)^2 = (a-1 -a-1)^2 $$

Combine like terms, and we get:
$$ (a-1-a-1)^2 = (-2)^2 $$

Simplify, and we get:
$$ (-2)^2 = 4 $$

Now we look at $((2a-1) - (2a+3))^2$.  We'll do the exact same process.  First we distribute the minus sign into the $(2a+3)$.  So we get:
$$ ((2a-1) - (2a+3))^2 = ((2a-1) - 2a - 3)^2 $$

Next we drop the unnecessary parentheses on the $2a-1$, and we get:
$$ ((2a-1) - 2a - 3)^2 = (2a-1 - 2a-3)^2$$

Then we combine like terms to get:
$$ (2a-1-2a-3)^2 = (-4)^2 $$

And simplify to get:
$$ (-4)^2 = 16 $$

To summarize, we have $((a-1) - (a+1))^2 = 4$ and $((2a-1) -(2a+3))^2 = 16$.  Therefore:
$$ \sqrt{((a-1) - (a+1))^2 + ((2a-1) - (2a+3))^2} = \sqrt{4 + 16} = \sqrt{20} $$

And this can further be simplified to $2\sqrt{5}$ but based on your textbook's answer I guess you aren't expected to do that.

Comment: Why does $(a+1)^2$ and $(2a+3)^2$ change to $(a-1)^2$ and $(2a-3)^2$

Comment: They don't.  $-(a+1)$ changes to $-a-1$.  Likewise for the other.  Distributing the minus sign.

Comment: @WillJ, I updated the answer to add more details.

Comment: that's very kind of you, thanks :)